# How can I create this photoshop effect with text-shadow

Tags: html, css, photoshop

[image]

How can I create this efect with text-shadow?

Comment: It may be a good idea to show the *result* of the effect as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text-shadow: #71AB32 0 1px 0;
```

Comment: he doesn't want any blur as it appears (see spread and size), so last 1px should be 0, no?

Answer (score 2):

[CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) has the kind of stuff you are after.

e.g. use the CSS3 text-shadow property.

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #71ab32;/*alter as needed*/
              ^   ^   ^
              |   |   +-- blur radius
              |   +-- Y offset
              +-- X offset
```

Just be aware that only the latest browsers support this (e.g. not IE)

Answer (score 0):

you can use text as an image for perfect output

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I did this mistake when I was kid :D now I do understand when to put answer and when to put comment Though I apologize for my comment kinda answer, & I appreciate your concern for the SO :)